# SQL counting and grouping unique values

Tags: sql, count, group-by, unique, distinct

I need to count the number of occurrences of each "score" and group them by "make" according to the fake dataset below:

```
make   | model  | score
Honda    Accord    9
Honda    CRV       9
Honda    Prelude   8
Toyota   Camry     8
Toyota   Tundra    8
Ford     F150      7
Ford     Tempo     7
Ford     Focus     8
```

This is what I need - 1 row for each make and score combination:

```
make   | score | count
Honda      9       2
Honda      8       1
Toyota     8       2
Ford       7       2
Ford       8       1
```

I'm not concerned with order ATM. I've tried several versions using distincts but can't seem to get the desired output.

Followup: I'd like to add rows to the output where a Make has a count of 0 (none) for any possible score value (in this case its {7, 8, 9}).

The output would change to:

```
make   | score | count
Honda      9       2
Honda      8       1
Honda      7       0
Toyota     9       0
Toyota     8       2
Toyota     7       0
Ford       9       0
Ford       8       1
Ford       7       2
```

Comment: `...(count distinct score)... group by make`.  seen alot of these today...  Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534540/count-function-with-month-convert

Comment: post your attempt and learn how `group by` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT make, score, count(1)
FROM {your_table}
GROUP BY make,score
```

Comment: I'd also like the output to include rows for which a Make had a count of zero for any value in the "Score" column. For example, Honda has 2 Makes with score 9, but Toyota and Ford both have 0, while Honda has 0 Makes with score of {8, 9}, and Toyota also has 0 Makes of score 7. I'd like the output to include those rows.

Comment: Tell me what did you try.